# Allow only zoom out until bounds

Tags: zooming, openlayers

I try to figure out, how to limit the zoom factor to the bounds (defined via restrictedExtent), means that you only can zoom out, as long as you not touch the bounds on two sides of the viewport.

What i found, was this question ([Min/max zoom level in OpenLayers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240610/min-max-zoom-level-in-openlayers)) but somehow I could not figure out how to get this to work.

I am working on the actual OpenLayers version 2.11.

Any solutions?

Comment: Post what version of OpenLayers you are using as well as anything code examples you have already tried and we may be able to help better :)

Comment: I added the version to my question. As said, i search to documentation for a setting to restrict zoom levels but but there is none that actually works. Am i missing something?