# Openlayers - How to limit number of zooms in google/bing layers?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, openlayers, openstreetmap

I want to have 5 zoom levels only in google/bing layer in OL.

http://jsfiddle.net/Alophind/j97mw/

In this Fiddle example I have OSM/Bing/Google layers.

for OSM layer I did it like this :

```
var resolutions = OpenLayers.Layer.Bing.prototype.serverResolutions.slice(16, 20);
var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM", null, {
        zoomOffset: 16,
        resolutions: resolutions
    });
```

How can I do the same with google & bing layer ?
I want to show the zoom bar on the left with only 5 zoom levels.

Thx.

Comment: Have you read [this very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240610/min-max-zoom-level-in-openlayers)?

Comment: I've seen that , it works with OSM layer but not with google layer

Comment: Even overwriting the `isValidZoomLevel()` function didn't work?

Comment: It didn't give me the zoom offset. 
Ill update question with JSFiddle example.